# How to test for a critical mass - dummy variables?

Tags: categorical-data

Part of my thesis is to test where the critical mass lies. Let's assume that we want to test the influence of a certain ethnic group (x) on the performance of the whole group (members of ethnic group x and ethnic group y). The assumption/hypothesis is that if there are one or two members of group x among the whole group, the overall performance does not increase. However, if there are three or more members of group x in the group the overall performance increases. Now I have to test for this hypothesis.

> Hypothesis 1a: There is no relationship between one group memeber of x and the >performance. 
>   Hypothesis 1b: There is no relationship between two group memebers of x and the >performance. 
>   Hypothesis 1c: There is a positive relationship between the critical mass of group >memebers of x (at least three) and the performance.

I was thinking about using dummy variables in order to test for it. The idea was to use 0 as the reference group and then use 3 dummy variables. (Variable1: 1=1, all others = 0; Variable2: 2=1; all others=0; Variable 3: 3 or more = 1; all others=0) Then I would run a regression and see whether the Variables are significantly different from the constant.

Would you recommend this procedure? I have the feeling I miss out on some important aspects. I appreciate every reccomendation and new point of view on my problem.

Comment: The problem is that I am looking at a longitudinal study and not at survey data. I think I learned, that I am not able to use simple tests like these if I have longitudinal data. What do you mean by: "the Hypothesis is wrong" ? The hypothesis is the one I have to prove, so if something is wrong then it is the analysis and I have to adapt the analysis to the hypothesis but the hypothesis is given. Sorry I am really confused with my analysis :(

Comment: They hypothesis is wrong = The hypothesis is formulated incorrectly. You can't have a 3-part hypothesis; that's not how hypothesis testing works.

Answer (score 0):

In short, no. The formulation of the hypothesis is wrong.

As stated, you are doing 3 separate tests because you have 3 separate hypotheses.

Second of all, what makes you think this is a regression problem, per se? From your description, you're looking at the difference in mean performance when group X is present and when it's absent. So you really just have two means to compare, which would be done with a t-test or Z test (assuming randomness and the other assumptions are met).